# Sincronizar sql

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual requiero sincronizar una base de datos mysql locahost, con una mysql montada en un servidor, para efectos de que si se va el internet poder seguir trabajando en la aplicaion php web. cual seria la manera adecuada de realizar esta operacion Muhcas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas en primera instancia hacer la [replicación](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/mysql-replicacion/) con mysql. Si quieres que una aplicación web este disponible aun si se cae uno de los servidores, necesitas meter un proxy http para balanceo y carga, apache y nginx tienen estas opciones si mi memoria no me falla.
No obstante necesitarías en total 3 servidores mínimo, un proxy y dos esclavos. El proxy debes asegurarte que siempre este disponible, debe estar en datacenter.

Otra opcion es contratar servicios de dominio, que si un servidor se cae te direccionara a otro, no recuerdo si cloudflare te da ese servicio.

Comment: te lo agradezco ya tengo claridad de como hacerlo con tu respuesta